# What are _spPageContextInfo.fid and _spPageContextInfo.nid in SharePoint 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, csom, jsom, spfx

I am getting values as shown below while executing _spPageContextInfo.fid and _spPageContextInfo.nid in the console in my SharePont 365 site but am not getting for what these values are used here.

```
 _spPageContextInfo.fid
  16604
 _spPageContextInfo.nid
  337
```

Can anybody help me to understand these values??

Comment: As much as I could find (absolutely no info on Google :) ) `fid` stands for `feature ID` and `nid` stands for `notification ID`. These might be used in feature / notification contexts :)

Comment: `nid` is used in [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659501(v=office.14).aspx) (probably nowhere else)

Comment: `fid` is used [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247054.aspx#properties)

Comment: @Gintas Thanks for the above links.As you have told am not getting any details about it on google.and i would like to know more about these values and their uses.

Comment: If Microsoft hasn't documented it is not meant to be used by 3rd parties; so even IF it is cool functionality you/your clients won't be able to call on Microsoft for support. Also note in Modern Experiences there will no longer be a _spPageContextInfo global object. You have to make a REST call to get the ContextInfo. Now the ``_spPageContextInfo.webPermMasks`` IS a cool and handy object

Comment: Quick comment on the line from Danny.  As he mentions, stay away from the window variable, and stick with the ContextInfo object.  It's worth noting that the full contents of the old window variable are available as pageContext.legacyPageContext . You don't need to make the call to get the ContextInfo either.  It will be on that object and kept up to date as the user navigates, etc.

Comment: What I have observed that for a particular tenant nid and fid reamins sames.